# Angular 2 app not supporting in IE11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, httpbrowsercapabilities

I have an angular 2 app setting up with webpack. I want to support the app in Internet explorer 11.
In my **package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --progress",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p --progress --config=webpack.prod.config.js",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "local": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 3000",
    "tslint": "tslint -c tslint.json src/app/**/*.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.8",
    "angular2-cool-storage": "1.2.1",
    "angular2-highcharts": "^0.4.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "lodash": "^4.16.3",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.13",
    "ng2-slimscroll": "1.2.1",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^5.1.0",
    "ngx-tooltip": "0.0.9",
    "ngx-uploader": "^2.2.8",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.2.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.7"
  },
  "repository": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^6.0.53",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "codelyzer": "2.0.0-beta.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.24.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "retyped-gapi.auth2-tsd-ambient": "0.0.0-1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "ts-loader": "2.2.2",
    "tslint": "4.5.1",
    "typescript": "^2.0.10",
    "typings": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/*",
    "**/*-aot.ts"
  ]
}
```

**webpack.config.json**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.ts',
    output: {
        path: './dist',
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {    //Only required for development environment
        historyApiFallback:true,
        stats: 'minimal'
    },
    devtool:'source-map', //Only required for development environment
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.css$/,  loader: 'raw', exclude: /node_modules/},
            {test: /\.css$/,  loader: 'style!css?-minimize', exclude: /src/},
            {test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw'},
            {test:/\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader!angular2-template-loader'},
            {include: /\.json$/, loaders: ["json-loader"]}
            ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['','.js','.ts', '.json']
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html'
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: 'static' }
        ])
    ]    
}
```

The error in console window is

> SCRIPT5022: Error: Can't resolve all parameters for PlanningComponent:
>   ([object Object], [object Object], ?, [object Object]).

It is some problem with optional parameter. And also some times it throws some other errors like 
S

> CRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number

But it is not happening in other browsers.

Comment: ok i think i am crazy but can i ask a stupid question are you manipulating the DOM

Comment: @Tarek.Eladly yes

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to uncomment some lines in the `polyfills.ts` file ? (same level that `index.html`)

If not, you should have a look to this file and uncomment all lines required for IE11.

I hope it will solve your problem !

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is not related to Webpack, polyfills, nor—as somebody asked in a comment—whether you're manipulating the DOM or not.

It's related to Angular's Dependency Injection system.

The error is simply saying that the third parameter you're seeking to inject into the `PlanningComponent` constructor cannot be resolved. This is because Angular cannot find the [DI token](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#dependency-injection-tokens) in the injector for `PlanningComponent` or in any of the parent injectors all the way up to the root injector.

In addition to Dependency Injection, the Angular Docs have a very good overview on Hierarchical Injectors, which might be helpful in learning more about the subject: https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.

Happy to provide more information, but this is as far as I can go with the details you've provided so far. Hope it proves helpful!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have the problem in other browsers, And also some times it throws some other errors like SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number

Answer (score 0):

IE11, amongst a few other older browsers, require a polyfill for ES6 `Reflect` for Dependency Injection. `core-js` provides this, which you already seem to have installed: https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#ecmascript-6-reflect.

There are a couple ways to go about this:

- If you're using the `@angular/cli`, you'll simply need to uncomment the relevant line in your `polyfills.ts` file (see link below).
- If you're *not* using the CLI, you'll need to import the relevant polyfills at the beginning of your bundle entry to ensure `Reflect` is available to resolve dependencies. This should basically look very similar to the CLI's `polyfills.ts` file anyway.

For reference, this is the blueprint for the polyfills file provided by the CLI via the Angular default schematics: https://github.com/angular/devkit/blob/v6.0.5/packages/schematics/angular/application/files/src/polyfills.ts#L41. Note I'm linking to the current version—v6.0.5—at the time of this writing.

Additionally, the Angular docs also provide a handy list of polyfills, both mandatory and suggested, including everything you'd need to support IE: https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#polyfill-libs.

Hope this helps!